# How can I setup an Laravel project on IIS 7.5?

Tags: php, laravel, iis, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a php application that I write using Laravel framework. I developed it using XAMPP server which was running fine.

I want to move it to a production server where I can use IIS 7.5 to manage my applications.

Here is what I have done

1. I installed IIS
2. I installed [PHP Manager](https://phpmanager.codeplex.com/downloads/get/253209)

Created a folder called `laravel` in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`
 2. Using PHP Manager I changed the PHP version to 5.6.18
 3. In my php.ini of the version 5.6.18 I enabled the following lines

> ```
> extension_dir = "ext"
> cgi.force_redirect = 0
> cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
> fastcgi.impersonate = 1
> fastcgi.logging = 0
> extension=php_mbstring.dll
> extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
> extension=php_mysql.dll
> extension=php_mysqli.dll
> extension=php_openssl.dll
> extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
> date.timezone = "ENTER YOUR TIMEZONE HERE"
> session.entropy_length = 32
> ```

4. I installed composer with php 5.6.18
5. I imported the `.httaccess` file located in the public folder using URL Rewrite Model in IIS. This step created a `web.config` file. Then I moved it to the public folder.
6. I converted my `Laravel` to Application in IIS
7. I added phpinfo.php file in the root of my laravel all and I was able to see it via the browser.

But I can't access my laravel app.

When I go to http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php I get an error

```
HTTP 500 Internal error
```

I followed the blogs below to get where I am at now

http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/installing-laravel-4-in-windows-7-with-iis7/

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/iis7-laravel-5?page=2

How can I get laravel app to run?

Comment: Did you do: Grant full control of the folder "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\laravel\storage" to IUSR ***This is very important!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figure it out.

Everything I have done was correct except of 2 things

1. I changed the Physical Path on the application to point to the public folder instead of the root.
2. I IIS User need to have full control permission on the `bootstrap/cache` and `storage`  << this is very critical step to get everything to work

Everything is running fine now.

Comment: if do this what url to accress index.blade.php