# How to use laravel routes in iis7

Tags: laravel, iis, iis-7

Is there a way to make Laravel routes be used in IIS 7?  I can already access the index.php but can't access other routes, below is the error when I click a button login.

[image]

Comment: Have you taken a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640159/how-can-i-setup-an-laravel-project-on-iis-7-5

Comment: I'm having a problem importing my .htaccess file using URL Writer, it doesn't give an option to import .htaccess

Comment: @Andrew got the error "could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied", I added a "web.config" file on my public folder.

Comment: you probably need to add the ```IUSR``` account to the ```IIS_USERS``` group. See here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/laravel-permissions-on-iis-server

Comment: I tried the solution on the link you provided but no luck

Comment: For information about "Laravel Install on Windows IIS", you can refer to this link: https://jimfrenette.com/2016/09/laravel-iis-windows-install/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this, it seems that I just need to add "IUSR" for the folder storage which gives me permission to access the folder. Thank you for giving me references!